# Using Mixins in flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

I am not able to use mixins in my flutter app, It says:

> The class 'UserModel' can't be used as a mixin because it extends a class other than Object

[image: error]

Comment: it looks like Udemy's Flutter course, there is the solution for this error in the MUST READ documents

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It wasn't officially possible to have mixins with that extends something for a long time.

It has been recently enabled, but with another syntax:

```
mixin UserModel on Model {
  // do some stuff
}
```